# GKE usage metering template requests only one data source although the documents says three data sources are required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, looker-studio

I'm trying to visualize GKE usage metering data using a Data Studio dashboard following the official document.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering#view_in_data-studio

It says

> We created a dashboard you can copy into your project. When you copy the dashboard, you are prompted to select three data sources you just created.

I guess the three data sources means a data source created from the cost breakdown table, gke_cluster_resource_consumption and gke_cluster_resource_usage.

However, when creating a copy from the data studio template, I can choose only one data source.
[image: showing after clicking the Copy button]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Google documentation is outdated.

However, if you follow the documentation, at the point where you clone the dashboard, it just asks you to create one DataSource (=cost breakdown table).  What happens when you select this source?  Maybe the error is only in the word "three".

The other two DataSources you mentioned are cited in other part of the document, so I guess they're for other purpose.  The Google's dashboard have other linked DataSources, but they're not used.

[image: DataSources]
[image: Blended DataSources]

So, apparently, you need only one DataSource to make this dashboard work.

If this doesn't work, I would say you're out of lucky.  Try to ask Google in some community forum to fix their documentation.

Comment: When I used one data source before, it failed. But, I probably made a mistake on the other point.
I tried it again from scratch. It works.
Thank you for answering my stupid questions ;)